# Orbit type and conjugacy class

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

I am studying an article on symmetric configurations and I found a statement about group theory that I can not understand.

Definition: Each orbit is associated a conjugacy class of subgroups of $G$, called the **orbit type** of the orbit.

Affirmation: if an orbit has type $(H)$ say, then at least one of the points $x$ of
the orbit has isotropy subgroup $G_x = H$.

Apparently the assertion results from the fact that $G_y=gG_xg^{-1}$ since that $y=gx$, because the author proof before the affirmation.

My question is:
associated means that exists a bijection between each orbit and the conjugation class of a subgroup?
how can I proof the affirmation? I've try to use that $G_y=gG_xg^{-1}$, but without sucess.

Notations:

$G$ is a group;

$H$ is a subgroup of G;

$G_x=\{g\in G: gx=x\}$;

orbit of $x$ over $G$ is $G.x=\{gx: g\in G\}$

The group $G$ acts with the set $X$ and $x\in X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given an orbit $A$, the associated conjugacy class consists of the stabilizers $G_x$ of all the elements $x\in A$. It is easy to prove that (1) stabilizers are subgroups of $G$ and (2) the stabilizers of elements of $A$ constitute exactly one conjugacy class of subgroups of $G$.